# How to dynamically add typeahead in ng-bootstrap? Angular 7/8

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, formarray

I'm using ng-bootstrap as my front end design in Angular.

I need to use its TypeAhead component which is this [TypeAhead of Ng-Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#focus)

but the thing is I am implementing a FormArray. I need to dynamically add the TypeAhead. Its working fine until I used the "tab" key since it uses one instance, when I pressed tab it all opens at the same time.

[image]

I tried to have a work around.

```js
focus(event, i) {
  this.focusArr[i] = new Subject<string>();
    this.focusArr[i].next(event)'
    this.indexCount = i;
  }  
}

click(event, i){
  this.clickArr[i] = new Subject<string>();
  this.clickArr[i].next(event);
  this.indexCount = i;
}

searchItem = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
  var click = this.clickArr[this.indexCount];
  var focus = this.focus[this.indexCount];
  const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
  const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = click.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
  const inputFocus$ = focus;

  return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
    map(term => (term === '' ? this.itemListHolder
      : this.itemListHolder.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
}
```

Then the html is:

```html
<input id="typeahead-focus" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose an Item" formControlName="itemSelected"
    [ngbTypeahead]="searchItem" (focus)="focus($event.target.value, i)"
    (click)="click($event.target.value, i)" #instance="ngbTypeahead" />
```

Here is the error message:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I have no idea anymore :(

Comment: Change your code to make the text input id unique across all inputs where you are using the type-ahead. Using `id="typeahead-focus"` for all the inputs is causing the behavior you're seeing. That needs to be different for each input.

Comment: @R.Richards I changed it to id="typeahead+i" but its not working also id="typeahead+{{i}}"

Comment: You may have to use `i` for the `formControlName` value as well. FormArrays... so much fun. :| Something to read: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: @R.Richards I didn't have to add index count when I didn't use the type ahead of ng-bootstrap. It has to do something with the observable

Answer (score 0):

think I got it

`searchItem` is used for all typeaheads. inside `searchItem` there is dependency on `indexCount`:

```js
var click = this.clickArr[this.indexCount];
var focus = this.focus[this.indexCount];
```

`indexCount` is the **last clicked or focused element**. `this.clickArr[this.indexCount]` could be read as 'click observable for last clicked element'. And each typeaheads would listen to the last clicked element.

As a solution, I would provide input to subscribe to events.

```js
searchItem(input: HTMLInputElement) {
   return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
      const click = fromEvent(input, 'click');
      const focus = fromEvent(input, 'focus');
   }
}
```

and in the html

```html
<input #input [ngbTypeahead]='searchItems(input)' />
```

Feels like easier when supporting arrays of observables for click and focus events.

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: added the possible solution. sorry, didn't test. setting up things will take time

Comment: Can you share some Plunker or Share via glitch.com?

Answer (score 0):

It`s litle stupid.. but working!

So:

Instead
`[ngbTypeahead]="searchFactorMain"`
use
`[ngbTypeahead]="getSearchFactorMain(i)"`

```
    getSearchFactorMain(i) {
        return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
            const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
            this.focusArr[i] = new Subject<string>();
            const inputFocus$ = this.focusArr[i];

            return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$).pipe(
                map((term) =>
                    (term === '' ? this.factorData : this.factorData.filter((v:any) => v.factorName.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)),
                ),
            );
        };
    }
```

and

replace (focus) in template with:
`(focus)="focusFactor($any($event).target.value, i)"`

```
focusFactor(target: any, i: number) {
        this.focusArr[i].next(target);
        this.factorIndexCount = i;
    }
```

voila !